# How to save stdout instead of printing directly on console?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, stdout

When I call some third party library and there may be some stdout from it.
For example `pd.read_sql`,
and there may be output like

```
2022-08-01 17:15:47,216 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'

2022-08-01 17:15:47,217 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()

2022-08-01 17:15:47,260 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'

2022-08-01 17:15:47,260 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00024s] ()

2022-08-01 17:15:47,346 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT DATABASE()

2022-08-01 17:15:47,346 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()

2022-08-01 17:15:47,476 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = %s AND table_name = %s

2022-08-01 17:15:47,476 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00027s] ('test', 'select * from A')

2022-08-01 17:15:47,520 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select * from A

2022-08-01 17:15:47,520 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
```

But I really don't want them to print directly onto console, instead I want to save them temporarily and use them when I want.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Do you want to save the query itself or do you want to save the result of the query? [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218963/storing-sql-statements-in-a-properties-file-to-be-used-by-python-scripts) could help. You can also save the result to a panda dataframe using `pd.read_sql_query()`

Comment: @Bunny nope~ I don't want to save the query statement. But when I have done the query, there is some stdout messages automatic which comes from the procedure of query from some third party library, I just want to save the stdout messages instead of printing them directly onto console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to save stdout instead of printing directly on console?

This looks like task for [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout), simple usage example

```
import contextlib
import io
def printing_func():
    print("Hello World")
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(io.StringIO()) as f:
    printing_func()
s = f.getvalue()
print(s)
```

output

```
Hello World
```